# Rig Cable connected to head and body

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent

I need your help. I have a model that has a cable attached to the back of the head and body. I want the bottom part of the cable attached to the body to follow the body bone and the top part attached to the head to follow the head bone, deforming the bone chain and stretching as the head rotates.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: So have you tried my solution? If you've found a better one please tell   ;)

Comment: Yes it worked, I had some bugs because I'm using version 2.8 beta, But I did the armature a second time and then it worked without any problem, Thanks for the solution. =D

Comment: oh ok, because it's not an easy solution so if you had found a simpler I would have been curious to know  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ***Stretch To*** constraint:

- Build your cable, create an armature, with a small bottom bone, a central bone as long as the cable, and a small top bone that you unparent.

[image]

- Select the armature, go in *Edit* mode, in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Display*, choose *B-Bone*. Select the central bone and in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > *Bendy Bones*, segment your bone (for example 6).

[image]

- Switch to Pose mode, keep the central bone selected, in the *Properties* panel > *Bone Constraints* give it a *Stretch To* constraint with the same armature as *Target* and the top bone as *Bone*.

[image]

- Back in *Properties* panel > *Bone*, enable *Use Custom Handle References* and in the *In* and *Out* fields choose the bottom bone and the top bone so that the central bone will bend properly.

[image]

- Parent the cable to the armature *With Automatic Weight*.

[image]

- Move the top bone, the cable should follow.

[image]

- What you could do to give it the right bend is to put an empty at the exact same position as the top bone, give the top bone a *Child Of* constraint, then move the empty to where it is supposed to be in the back of the head and parent it to a bone.

[image]